# Blocking specific keyboard key combinations using c#

Tags: c#, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to block certain keyboard shortcuts using c# in windows applications.
All the key combinations will be specified in config file.

Like :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

What should be the configuration in `app.config` for this? And please help me with some sample code or examples.

Comment: Do you want your application to block these keys for the entire system? Or only when your application has focus?

Comment: You can't do that with app.config. You have to do that programatically (probably through P/Invoke to the Win32 API).

Comment: @Bevan, I want to do that for entire system.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes, why is it not possible to do it via app.config ?
Cant we do it by passing the combination keys as paremeters to the P/Invoke to the Win32 API ??

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that can be accomplished system wide by the app.config of your application. You will need to use a tool such as SteadyState.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SteadyState